# Merge multiple text files taking into account dates with Python

Tags: python, date

I am trying to merge text files into combined one with Python.
However, has some issues with that.
The description of what I am trying to do:

1. There are several text files in some specific folder. Coulbd be 3 or more files. The sript should with any number of files.
2. Each file contains DATES and some data between DATES. Example of text files will be later.
3. I need to merge all files in the folder and place data from each file at their DATES.

Example of 3 text files to be merged:

1. file_1.txt has the following content:

DATES

1 JAN 2023 /

/

FILE_1 text1
12345

DATES

1 OCT 2027 /

/

FILE_1 text2
87944

2. file_2.txt has the following content:

DATES

1 MAR 2024 /

/

FILE_2 text1
9999

DATES

1 JAN 2026 /

/

FILE_2 text2
4578

3. file_3.txt has the following content:

DATES

1 JAN 2023 /

/

FILE_3 text1
8888

DATES

1 DEC 2030 /

/

FILE_3 text2
aaaaa

How they should be combined:

DATES

1 JAN 2023 /

/

FILE_1 text1
12345

FILE_3 text1
8888

DATES

1 MAR 2024 /

/

FILE_2 text1
9999

DATES

1 JAN 2026 /

/

FILE_2 text2
4578

DATES

1 OCT 2027 /

/

FILE_1 text2
87944

DATES

1 DEC 2030 /

/

FILE_3 text2
aaaaa

Here is the code which I created by using dictionaries.
So I have the main file main_file.data (let's say it is file_1.txt) and all other files which I want to merge with the main file are inside folder "input_files_folder/". However, stucked at the issue in merging all subdictionaries together, keeping into account the fact that they can have the same keys (date), but different values for that keys. So in case subdictionaries have the same key, their content should be added to each other.
Maybe there is an easier way to merge text files, and I complicated too much.
Seek for you help. Thank you!

```
import os
import re

main = "main_file.data"

input_folder = "input_files_folder/"

output_path = "output.txt"

output = open(output_path, "w")

inputs = []

for file in os.listdir(input_folder):
    inputs.append(os.path.join(input_folder, file))


list_of_words = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"]

list_of_words_DATES = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"]

list_to_add = []

my_dict = {}

string = ""

list_of_dates = []

number_of_files = 1

for idx, fname in enumerate(inputs):
    flag = 0
    flag_DATES = 0
    flag_content = 0
    list_to_add = []
    
    my_dict[str(idx)] = {}
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines2 = [line.strip() for line in f]
        for line in lines2:
            new = re.split(r"\s+", line)
            
            if len(new) > 1 and new[1] in list_of_words:
                flag = 1
                string = str(int(new[0])) + " " + str(new[1]) + " "  + str(new[2])
                #my_dict[string] = ""
                list_to_add = []
                list_of_dates.append(string)
            else:
                flag = 0
                list_to_add.append(new)
            
            if len(string) >1:
                #print(idx)
                #print("AAAAA")
                my_dict[str(idx)][string] =  list_to_add
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code reads the main file and input files, extracts the date blocks, and appends the data to the corresponding date in the date_data_dict. Finally, it writes the sorted merged content to the output file:

```
import os
import re
from collections import defaultdict

main = "main_file.data"
input_folder = "input_files_folder/"
output_path = "output.txt"

inputs = [os.path.join(input_folder, file) for file in os.listdir(input_folder)]

date_pattern = re.compile(r'\d{1,2}\s(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\s\d{4}')

date_data_dict = defaultdict(list)

def process_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        date_blocks = content.split("DATES")[1:]

        for block in date_blocks:
            date_match = date_pattern.search(block)
            if date_match:
                date = date_match.group()
                date_data_dict[date].append(block[date_match.end():].strip())

process_file(main)
for input_file in inputs:
    process_file(input_file)

with open(output_path, "w") as output:
    for date, data_list in sorted(date_data_dict.items()):
        output.write("DATES\n\n")
        output.write(date + " /\n\n")
        output.write("\n\n".join(data_list))
        output.write("\n\n")
```

**UPDATE:**
If you don't want to use defaultdict you can use a regular dictionary and check if the key exists before appending the data. If the key doesn't exist, create a new list with the data:

```
date_data_dict = {}

def process_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        date_blocks = content.split("DATES")[1:]

        for block in date_blocks:
            date_match = date_pattern.search(block)
            if date_match:
                date = date_match.group()
                if date in date_data_dict:
                    date_data_dict[date].append(block[date_match.end():].strip())
                else:
                    date_data_dict[date] = [block[date_match.end():].strip()]
```

Comment: Thank you Matteo! Do you think it can work without defaultdict?

Comment: Updated the code without default dict. @Al_Pacino

Comment: Tested on the data I havce, and it works very well. I added one line just to be sure that it will group dates if they are separated by tab or space like this one: block = block.replace('\t', ' '). One question: is there any way to make the code work in case there are several dates under DATES word? for example like: <br/> `DATES  <br/>  1 JAN 2023 / <br/>1 FEB 2023 / <br/>1 MAR 2023 / <br/>/`